# last picture flashes through image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason I cannot understand, the last image is flashing through for a split second. The whole thing works about 100% right except with the last image. Can anyone please assist with this... I really am stuck and in need of help.

The code is all bellow. Or here on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVFBb/5/)

```
//CSS
<style type="text/css">
#slideshow img {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    top:100px; left:350px;
    z-index:0;
}    
#slideshow img.active{
    z-index:10;
}
.animate {
    animation-name:anim;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes anim
{
    0%   {left:350px;}
    50%  {left:750px; top:-100px; transform:rotate(50deg);}
    51%  {z-index:10;}
    52%  {z-index:0;}
    100% {left:350px;}
}
</style>

//javascript
<script>
function slider() {
    var active = $('.active', '#slideshow');
    active.css({ 'z-index': 10 });
    if (active.hasClass('last')) {
        active.siblings(":first").css({ 'z-index': 9 });
    } else {
        active.next().css({ 'z-index': 9 });
    }

    active.removeClass('active');
    active.addClass('animate');
    setTimeout(function () {
        active.css({ 'z-index': 0 });
        if (active.hasClass('last')) {
            active.siblings(":first").addClass('active');
        } else {
            active.next().addClass('active');
        }
        active.removeClass('animate');
    }, 1000);

}

$(function () {
    setInterval("slider()", 2000);
});
</script>

//html
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="picture/img1.jpg" style="position:absolute;" class="active" />
    <img src="picture/img2.jpg" style="position:absolute;"                />
    <img src="picture/img3.jpg" style="position:absolute;" class="last"   />
</div>
```

All help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Need help ? Go there and create a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't save your last image as a "progressive" jpg? I have seen this type of behaviour while creating a slideshow with progressive images.

Comment: what do you mean by save as a progressive? where would that property be set? or how would I not save it as progressive?

Comment: That depends on the program you're using to save the images. Photoshop has such a feature when using the "save for web and devices" option.

Comment: I used paint.net and all I did was save the image... I'll try use a different image then, just to be sure. Changing the picture didn't work.